# How to hide sender email id while sending email by CDO in excel vba

Tags: excel, outlook, smtp, cdo.message, vba

I want to hide **senders email ID** but not the **recipient name** like below

[image]

Below is part of my script to send email by **CDO**

```
With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "open.dealerz@gmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = "Dealer <open.dealerz@gmail.com>" 
    .Subject = "Test"
    .TextBody = ""
    .Send
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to resolve recipients against the address book. Then you will see names instead of email addresses. The [ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Recipients class (see the corresposning property of the MailItem class) attempts to resolve all the Recipient objects in the Recipients collection against the Address Book.

```
Sub CheckRecipients()  
 Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipients  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
 Set myRecipients = myItem.Recipients  
 myRecipients.Add("Aaron Con")  
 myRecipients.Add("Nate Sun")  
 myRecipients.Add("Dan Wilson")  
 If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then  
  For Each myRecipient In myRecipients  
   If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then  
    MsgBox myRecipient.Name 
   End If 
  Next  
 End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: giving compile error **user-defined type not defined** and highlight below code. 


`Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem`

Comment: The Outlook object model is used in the sample code.

Comment: But I am using **excel macro** and these objects pertain in **Outlook**. Is there any  method in excel vba to resolve recipients against the address book ?

Comment: Thanks, for all of your contribution but I got my answer and it is very simple to hide only sender ID. I just need to use comma (**,**) between name & ID in my code then recipient cannot see my sender address on his screen except sender name when I use this trick `From = """username"",<email@abc.com>"`. **:)**